# Why $4b^3p=2a^2+qb$ has no solutions for integers $a,b$ and two odd primes $p<q$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Empirically I do not find any integer solutions for $4b^3p=2a^2+qb$, where $a$ and $b$ are **non-zero** integers and $2<p<q$ are two odd primes.

If it is provable, why this equation does not provide a solution?

Comment: $a=b=0$ is a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Non-trivial solution: $p=3,q=47,a=1,b=2$

Comment: Since a counter example exists, this makes proving the original conjecture *problematic*.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this help!

Comment: Now I found also more solutions: (p=5,q=71,a=3,b=2), (p=7,q=103,a=3,b=2), (p=5,q=20359,a=44,b=32) and many more.

Comment: This equation indeed has solutions, but this one: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4051170/does-4b3pq-2a2b-has-a-solution-for-non-zero-integers-a-b-and-odd-primes?noredirect=1#comment8367526_4051170 does not provide me any solution.

Answer (score 0):

If $b=0$, we quickly find $a=0$, which indeed gives a solution.

Write $b=uv^2$ where $u$ is square-free.
Then
from $$2a^2=uv^2\cdot{(4u^2v^4p-q)} $$
we conclude that $v\mid a$ and write $a=vw$:
$$2w^2=u\cdot\underbrace{(4u^2v^4p-q)}_{\text{odd}} $$
We conclude $u=2t$ and so
$$w^2=t\cdot{(16t^2v^4p-q)} $$
It seems promising to find solutions with $w=1$ and $t=\pm1$, which amounts to looking for primes $p$ and integers $v$ such that one of $(2v)^4p\pm1$ is prime.
Even with these additional restrictions we find lots of solutions $(p,q,a,b)$, such as
$$ (3,47,1,2)^1, (5,79,1,2), (7, 113, 1, -2), \ldots, (41, 409999, 5, 50),\ldots,(97, 1553, 1, -2),\ldots, (983, 15727, 1, 2),
(991, 64946177, 8, -128),
(997, 1292113, 3, -18),\ldots (1000003, 38416115249, 7, -98),\ldots, (1000000007, 256000001791, 2, 8),\ldots$$

---

$^1$ see answer by *cr001*.

Comment: Thank you very much. My mistake was to not take a closer look at this equation, where for the following I really get no solution: $4b^3pq=2a^2+b$, where $a,b$ are non-zero integers and $p<q$ are odd primes (I feel a bit reluctant to reask for this equation, but would like to enter it as a new post -- please let me know if this is an erroneous conclusion).

Comment: If you like to take a look at this equation, I would be grateful for any hint: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4051170/does-4b3pq-2a2b-has-a-solution-for-non-zero-integers-a-b-and-odd-primes