# Does $4b^3pq=2a^2+b$ has a solution for non-zero integers $a,b$ and odd primes $p<q$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Just recently, I had an equation on my hands that I thought had no solutions:
[Why $4b^3p=2a^2+qb$ has no solutions for integers $a,b$ and two odd primes $p<q$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4051106/why-4b3p-2a2qb-has-no-solutions-for-integers-a-b-and-two-odd-primes-pq)

I was on a wrong path and now have an equation $4b^3pq=2a^2+b$ that really do not brings me any non-zero integer solution $a,b$ where $2<p<q$ are odd primes. What I see is that $b$ must be even and when I substitute $b=2t$ I have to solve $0=16t^3pq-t-a^2$ for $t$ (quadratic equation) and analyze the discriminant?

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that the solutions would be bigger than your brute force range?

Comment: I really run the brute force program (python) supporting big integers. If there is a solution, I would be very interested in this one.

Comment: Is this your original equation, or should I trust that the steps leading to this equation are arithmetically correct?

Comment: I did a minor mistake which I just fixed (in compliance with your answer) - the equation after substitution is $0=16t^2pq-a^2-t$. Your proof in your answer is very helpful - thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct resulting equation is of substituting $b=2t$ is:
$$16t^3pq=a^2+t$$

We transform our equation to:
$$(16t^2pq-1)t = a^2$$

Let $\ell$ be any prime factor of $t$, and let $\ell^n$ be the highest power of $\ell$ that divides $\color{red}{a}$. Then $\ell^{2n}$ is the highest power of $\ell$ that divides $a^2$; now $\ell$ does not divide $16t^2pq - 1$ at all, so $\ell^{2n}$ must also be the highest power of $\ell$ that divides $t$.

Since $\ell$ is arbitrary, we conclude that $t$ is in fact a square, say $t = g^2$. Then our equation becomes:
$$(16g^4pq-1)g^2 = a^2$$

which gives:
$$16g^4pq-1 = \left(\frac ag\right)^2$$

which is impossible, since the squares mod $16$ are $0, 1, 4, 9$.

Comment: Since $t$ is prime to $16t^2pq - 1$, one concludes directly that $16t^2pq - 1$ is a perfect square, which is impossible by an argument mod $4$.

Comment: Indeed, your method is quicker.

Answer (score 0):

More generally, the equation
$$
2b^3c=2a^2+b
\qquad\;\;\;\;
$$
has no integer solutions with $c > 0$ and $a,b\ne 0$.

Suppose otherwise.
\begin{align*}
\text{Then}\;\;&
2b^3c=2a^2+b
\qquad\qquad\qquad\;
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
2b^3c-b=2a^2
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
b(2b^2c-1)=2a^2
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
b(2b^2c-1) > 0
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
b > 0\;\;\text{(since $2b^2c-1 > 0)$}
\end{align*}
Next let $d=\gcd(a,b)$.

Then
$$
\left\lbrace
\begin{align*}
a&=da_1\\[4pt]
b&=db_1\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
\right.
\qquad\qquad\qquad\;\;\;
$$
for some integers $a_1,b_1$ with $b_1 > 0$ and $\gcd(a_1,b_1)=1$.
\begin{align*}
\text{Then}\;\;&
2b^3c=2a^2+b
\qquad\qquad\qquad\;\;\;\;
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
2(db_1)^3c=2(da_1)^2+db_1
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
2d^3b_1^3c=2d^2a_1^2+db_1
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
2d^2b_1^3c=2da_1^2+b_1
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
2d{\,\mid\,}b_1
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
hence $b_1=2db_2$ for some positive integer $b_2$.

Then since $\gcd(a_1,b_1)=1$ and $b_2{\,\mid\,}b_1$, it follows that $\gcd(a_1,b_2)=1$.
\begin{align*}
\text{Then}\;\;&
2d^2b_1^3c=2da_1^2+b_1
\qquad\qquad\qquad
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
2d^2(2db_2)^3c=2da_1^2+2db_2
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
16d^5b_2^3c=2da_1^2+2db_2
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
8d^4b_2^3c=a_1^2+b_2
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
b_2{\,\mid\,}a_1^2\
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
b_2=1\;\;\text{(since $\gcd(a_1,b_2)=1$)}
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
8d^4c=a_1^2+1
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
a_1^2\equiv -1\;(\text{mod}\;4)
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
which is not possible.